# AngularJS posting an empty array turns to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, angularjs, ruby, coffeescript

I'm using AngularJS 1.5 with Rails 3.2 on the backend and when I post a empty array by the time it gets to my Rails create method something has turned it from an empty array to a nil value.

```
  $scope.create = ->
    Invoice.save(
      {}
    ,
      invoice: InvoiceService.construct_json($scope)
    , (response) ->
      $location.path "/invoices"
    , (response) ->
      $scope.errors = response.data
      flash('alert', "Invoice has errors and cannot be saved", 2000)
    )
```

Just before Invoice.save I can see that timesheets_attributes is set to [].

```
construct_json: (scope) ->
  {
    # <snip irrelevant info>
    # Timesheets
    timesheets_attributes: _.map(scope.invoice.timesheets_attributes, (ts) ->
      _.omit(ts, 'job')
    )
  }
```

If I put byebug within my invoice controller create method I find that params[:invoice][:timesheets_attributes] is set to nil.

If I add a timesheet, then Angular posts the array correctly. Is there a way I can stop the array from being converted to a nil?

My current work around is to apply a before_filter, but this *hack* has stopped working now due to the introduction of cancancan. The load_and_authorize_resource of cancancan happens before any of the filters. I never really liked this hack and would like to find out why it's converting a perfection good empty array to a nil.

```
  def json_fix
    params[:invoice][:timesheets_attributes] ||= []
  end
```

Comment: Rail's action_dispatch will filter out empty arrays before cancancan get's the params. You can disable this feature with `config.action_dispatch.perform_deep_munge = false` since Rails 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you place the before_filter with my json_fix above the cancancan load_and_authorize_resource like so then it works.

```
before_filter :json_fix, only: [:update, :create]
before_filter :authenticate_staff!
load_and_authorize_resource  # Check cancancan
```